# My website is being redirected to http://guide.domain-error.com/

Tags: web

I created a website  with html, css, js, jquery and got a domain name at http://dot.tk.

The name of the website is http://onlinehtmleditor.tk.
But my browser is taking me to `http://guide.domain-error.com/search9870798707.php?keyword=onlinehtmleditor.tk/&uri=&uid=57499c974fcbe...`

I searched google but the results were solutions to remove domain-error not http://guide.domain-error.com/.

So how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the DNS records have not been updated yet.
The page you see is provider-specific, I see an other page when visiting your website.

[DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) ("Domain Name System") is used to get an [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) from a domain.
When you register a domain, the DNS records have to be actualized, your domain and your server's IP have to be added.

I assume you have already set up a server and assigned it to your domain (otherwise you have to do this in the domain management panel first).
If so, you only have to wait a little.
If you haven't assigned a server yet, do that first and check again a little time after this.

I hope I could help.